# joint (rappid) relative positioning of embeds

Tags: javascript, jointjs, rappid

When a cell is added as embed element, its x and y values are still relative to the paper instead of the parent. is there a way to use relative coordinates? And if not, any hint about how to make it happen?

thanks

Comment: my solution for now is to convert global coordinates into relative when presented to the properties inspector.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `position` method on `dia.Element` :

`childCell.position({parentRelative: true})`
it gets the position relatively to it's parent

or you can calculate position relatively to any point using `point.difference`. In this case you will get relative position of the `cell` to the `referenceCell`:

```
var point = g.Point(referenceCell.get('position'))
    .difference(cell.get('position'))
```